# R simecol and steady-state: rootfun cannot access to the SimObj equations slot

Tags: r, functional-programming, simulation, ode

I simulate ecological models (as ODE systems) using the [simecol](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simecol/index.html) package
framework which makes very easy the use and the sharing of ecological models
through the object class SimObj ([See here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simecol/vignettes/a-simecol-introduction.pdf)).

I want to implement a steady-state which stops the simulation once the derivatives become very low.

According to this
[vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/vignettes/rootSolve.pdf) and this [example](https://unamatematicaseltigre.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-simulate-bouncing-ball-in-r-more.html), you can implement it easily.

You have just to supply a custom solver which check the values of the derivatives.
The problem is that the custom solver does not look to be able reach the
`equations` slot of the SimObj.

I woulk like to keep this nice functionality of the equation slots to switch
easily between different types of functional response.

Here is the reproducible example:

## 1. Define the model

```
library(simecol)

upca_model <- function() {
  new("odeModel",
    main = upca_ode,
    equations = list(
      f1 = function(x, y, k){x * y}, # Lotka-Volterra
      f2 = function(x, y, k){f1(x, y, k) / (1 + k * x)} # Holling II
      ),
    times = c(from = 0, to = 300, by = 0.1),
    parms = c(a = 1, b = 1, c = 10, alpha1 = 0.2, alpha2 = 1,
      k1 = 0.05, k2 = 0, wstar = 0.1),
    init = c(u = 10, v = 5, w = 0.1),
    solver = "lsoda"
    )
}
```

## 2. Define the ODE system

```
upca_ode <- function(time, init, parms) {
  u <- init["u"]
  v <- init["v"]
  w <- init["w"]
  with(as.list(parms), {
    du <- a * u - alpha1 * f(u, v, k1)
    dv <- -b * v + alpha1 * f(u, v, k1) - alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)
    dw <- -c * (w - wstar) + alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)
    list(c(du, dv, dw))
})
}
```

## 3. Run it

```
upca <- upca_model()
equations(upca)$f <- equations(upca)$f2
test <- sim(upca)
```

## 4. Plot it nicely

```
plotupca <- function(obj, ...) {
  o <- out(obj)
  matplot(o[, 1], o[, -1], type = "l", ...)
  legend("topright", legend = c("u", "v", "w"), lty = 1:3,, bg = "white",
    col = 1:3)
}

plotupca(test)
```

[image: First equation: Holling II]

We can change the f equation, so we can easily change the functional response
type.

```
equations(upca)$f <- equations(upca)$f1
test <- sim(upca)
plotupca(test)
```

[image: Second equation: Lotka - Volterra]

We see that we did not need to run the simulation that long because it seems
that it has reached steady state after around 100 timesteps.

## 5. Implement the "steady-state checking"

So, we implement a solver that will stop the simulation once a steady state has been reached:

```
steady_state_upca <- function(time, init, func, parms) {
  root <- function(time, init, parms) {
    dstate <- unlist(upca_ode(time, init, parms))
    return(sum(abs(dstate)) - 1e-4)
  }
  lsodar(time, init, func, parms, rootfun = root)
}

equations(upca)$f <- equations(upca)$f1
solver(upca) <- steady_state_upca
test <- sim(upca)
#> Error in f(u, v, k1) : impossible de trouver la fonction "f"
```

So the function defined in the `equation` is not found anymore.

But if I add it in the ODE system, it works.

```
upca_ode <- function(time, init, parms) {
  u <- init["u"]
  v <- init["v"]
  w <- init["w"]
  #Â Definition of the function f:
  f <- function(x, y, k){x * y}
  with(as.list(parms), {
    du <- a * u - alpha1 * f(u, v, k1)
    dv <- -b * v + alpha1 * f(u, v, k1) - alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)
    dw <- -c * (w - wstar) + alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)

    list(c(du, dv, dw))
})
}

upca <- upca_model()
equations(upca)$f <- equations(upca)$f1
solver(upca) <- steady_state_upca
test <- sim(upca)
plotupca(test)
```

[image: Stop at the steady state]

We see that the simulation has stopped earlier (100 instead of 300), it has stopped since the steady
state was reached.

My question is: How can I make access the equations slot accessible to the
custom solver `lsodar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your example, I saw that your own solver is somewhat "wired", i.e. unnecessarily complicated. The solver is called by the sim function and gets what it needs, so there is no need to call upca_ode within. In addition, you call the *external* version of that function, not the object, so it has of course no access to "equations".

The (hopefully) good news is that package rootSolve contains already steady state solvers, that you can use.

See example below. The example below shows also, that it is quite easy to define an own solver. Please use the correct order of arguments.

Hope it helps!

Thomas

```
library(simecol)
library(rootSolve)

upca <- new("odeModel",
            main = function(time, init, parms) {
              u      <- init[1]
              v      <- init[2]
              w      <- init[3]
              with(as.list(parms), {
                du <-  a * u           - alpha1 * f(u, v, k1)
                dv <- -b * v           + alpha1 * f(u, v, k1) +
                  - alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)
                dw <- -c * (w - wstar) + alpha2 * f(v, w, k2)
                list(c(du, dv, dw))
              })
            },
            equations  = list(
              f1 = function(x, y, k){x*y},           # Lotka-Volterra
              f2 = function(x, y, k){x*y / (1+k*x)}  # Holling II
            ),
            times  = c(from=0, to=300, by=0.1),
            parms  = c(a=1, b=1, c=10, alpha1=0.2, alpha2=1,
                       k1=0.05, k2=0, wstar=0.1),
            init = c(u=10, v=5, w=0.1),
            solver = "lsoda"
)
upca@equations$f <- upca@equations$f2

plotupca <- function(obj, ...) {
  o <- out(obj)
  matplot(o[, 1], o[, -1], type = "l", ...)
  legend("topright", legend = c("u", "v", "w"), lty = 1:3, bg = "white", col = 1:3)
}

test <- sim(upca)
plotupca(test)

upca@equations$f <- upca@equations$f1
test <- sim(upca)
plotupca(test)


steady_state <- function(y, times, func, parms, steady.method) {
  time <- if (steady.method == "stode") {
    0
  } else {
    c(times[1], Inf)
  }
  steady(y, time, func, parms, method=steady.method)$y
}

equations(upca)$f <- equations(upca)$f1
solver(upca) <- steady_state

# fast direct approach, does not work with all models
test <- sim(upca, steady.method="stode")
out(test)

## slower, simulates model until approx. steady
test <- sim(upca, steady.method="runsteady")
out(test)
```